# woocommerce wordpress: sorting product trick

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a woocommerce site, and i'm facing a problem.
I'm updating the products, the products are sorted alphabetically, but all the new products in theyr name have a prefix, like this they're all showed in the 5th page.
I wanted to ask if there was a way to tell woocommerce to keep the alphabetical oreder but without counting the prefix
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When writing an answer, you may want to explain why you think your answer is correct, as it may be the case it is not targeting exactly the same problem and the explanation may help to see why

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is directly possible. There is a workaround though:

- Create a custom (post meta) field associated with the "product" post type (e.g abc_title)
- Replicate the product title (without prefix) in it, on the product save hook
- Use pre_get_posts action on the product page and update the sortorder field (abc_title)

For already added posts, you can write a script to replicate product titles.
Bingo!